# HttpContext.Current.Session values disappear

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I have an ASP.NET MVC application.
For some users we have the problem that from time to time their session context (in `HttpContext.Current.Session`) disappears (is cleared).
The session state element in the `web.config` looks like this:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" timeout="320" />
```

I check if session timed out like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.IsNewSession
```

But this was not the case. The values just disappeared.

What can cause this to happen? Could local settings influence the session context?

Comment: Related: [Losing Session State](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3515947/181087), [ASP.NET randomly losing session values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6958775/181087), [Don't redirect after setting a Session variable](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_), [Session variable and Cookies losing value](http://forums.asp.net/t/1811915.aspx?Session+variable+and+Cookies+losing+value)

Comment: But IMO, this one is the most important: [Think twice about using session state](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/). If you find alternatives to session state, it will keep you from having to spend countless hours troubleshooting when it "disappears" unexpectedly.

Comment: Thank you for all this information. But I already store my session out-of-proc or do I misunderstand the State Service (mode="StateServer")?